# React - Redux: How to bind this to a parent container in es6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a container component

```
import { AddQuest } from '../components/AddQuest.jsx'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { addQuestActionCreator } from '../actions.js'

const mapStateToProp = (
  dispatch,
  ownProps
) => {
  return {
    onClick: () => {
      console.log(this);// <-- this represents the window object instead the AddQuest component
      dispatch(addQuestActionCreator(this.input.value)); //<-- throws : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
      this.input.value = '';
    }
  }
}

export const AddQuestContainer = connect(
  undefined,
  mapStateToProp
)(AddQuest);
```

and a presentational component

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { addQuestActionCreator } from '../actions.js'

export const AddQuest = ({onClick}) => {
  let input;

  return(

    <div>
      <input type="text" ref={
        node =>{
          input = node;
        }
      }/>
      <button onClick={onClick.bind(this)}>Add quest</button>
    </div>
  )
};
```

But each time I click my button to add a quest. I have this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined.`

There is something wrong with my understanding on bind(this). I thought this will pass a ref of the presentational component to the container component.

Why is it not the case?

Comment: Redux discourages such use of a local state. You could pass synthetic event or extracted value to a handler instead - most probably your input does not have a complex structure and it is just a text. On the other case you could use redux-form component to handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass value through argument, and in `AddQuest` reset input

```
const mapStateToProp = (
  dispatch,
  ownProps
) => {
  return {
    onClick: (value) => {
      dispatch(addQuestActionCreator(value));
    }
  }
}

const AddQuest = ({ onClick }) => {
  let input;

  const send = () => {
    onClick(input.value)
    input.value = '';
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" ref = { 
        (node) => { input = node }
      } />
      <button onClick={ send }>Add quest</button>
    </div>
  )
};
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/31128/)

**Update**

[`arrow functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) don't not have their own `this` - so if you use `.bind(this)` inside arrow function `this` refers to parent score (in your example it will be `window` or `undefined` if you use [`strict mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)), you can rewrite your example with `ES2015` classes

```
class AddQuest extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>
      <input type="text" ref="text" />
      <button onClick={ this.props.onClick.bind(this) }>Add quest</button>
    </div>
  }
}

const mapStateToProp = (
  dispatch,
  ownProps
) => {
  return {
    onClick: function() {
      // this refers to AddQuest Object
      dispatch(addQuestActionCreator(this.refs.text.value));
      this.refs.text.value = '';
    }
  }
}
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/31156/)